# Как сделать таблицу HTML с нестандартной структурой?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, frontend

как сделать таблицу с такой структурой? Не могу догнать самостоятельно, буду рад любой помощи[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по комментарию на ответ выше, вы используете не табличную верстку. Так по чему бы вам не сделать так?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 20px;
}

.block {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.block__title {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.block__item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 -10px 10px;
}

.block__item:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.block__name,
.header__name {
    width: calc(60% - 20px);
}

.block__qvB,
.block__qvN,
.header__qvB,
.header__qvN {
    width: calc(20% - 20px);
}

.block__qvB,
.block__qvN,
.block__name {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 20px;
    min-height: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background: greenyellow;
    margin: 0 -10px 20px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

.header__name,
.header__qvB,
.header__qvN {
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="header__name">Продукты</div>
        <div class="header__qvB">Кол-во</div>
        <div class="header__qvN">Кол-во</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="block__title">Бисквит</div>
        <div class="block__item-wrap">
            <div class="block__item">
                <div class="block__name">Яицо</div>
                <div class="block__qvB">3шт</div>
                <div class="block__qvN">250</div>
            </div>
            <div class="block__item">
                <div class="block__name"></div>
                <div class="block__qvB"></div>
                <div class="block__qvN"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="block__item">
                <div class="block__name"></div>
                <div class="block__qvB"></div>
                <div class="block__qvN"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="block__title">Крем</div>
        <div class="block__item-wrap">
            <div class="block__item">
                <div class="block__name">Яицо</div>
                <div class="block__qvB">3шт</div>
                <div class="block__qvN">250</div>
            </div>
            <div class="block__item">
                <div class="block__name"></div>
                <div class="block__qvB"></div>
                <div class="block__qvN"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="block__item">
                <div class="block__name"></div>
                <div class="block__qvB"></div>
                <div class="block__qvN"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Руководство

[Таблицы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics) в HTML. Как оформить нужную таблицу.

## Ответ

Вот собственно конструкция таблицы. Стили добавьте сами.

```html
<body>
  <style>
    td:not([colspan]) {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Продукты</th>
        <th>Количество брутто</th>
        <th>Количество нетто</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Бисквит</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Яйцо</td>
        <td>3шт</td>
        <td>250</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Сухая глюкоза</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>11</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Мука слаюая</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>55</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><button>Добавить продукт</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: а если у меня таблица через display: table; сделана? как в таком случае ячейки объединить?

Comment: @ДараганМаксим На какой элемент `display: table;` поставили?

Comment: @ДараганМаксим хотя по идеи принцип тот же. Если на элемент `<td>` поставлен аттрибут `colspan или rowspan`, то ячейки должны объединится.

Comment: <div class="table-tr">
  <div class="table-td" colspan="3">Бисквит</div>
  <div class="table-td"></div>
  <div class="table-td"></div>
  <div class="table-td"></div>
</div>
пишу вот так, браузер атрибут колспан вообще не воспринимает

Comment: display: table; стоит на всю таблицу целиком

Comment: @ДараганМаксим на `.table-tr` нужно еще поставить `display: table-row`, а  `.table-td` - `display: table-cell`,